# Data not displaying in the right cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a section in my UITableView that's misbehaving. The other sections works fine.

I need to display a dictionary in the section of the tableview and the section should return the number of cells according to the number of items inside the dictionary which contains "1". I was able to display the header but the details that i need to display in the section displays on the section under it (sample: instead of displaying data in section 3 it displays the data in section 4 in its third cell).
Here's what i've got so far:

```
if(indexPath.section == 3)
{
    NSString *strIncentives = [[self.jobDetailDict objectForKey:@"sub_slots"] objectForKey:@"incentives_and_benefits"];
    NSData *jsonData = [strIncentives dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    CGSize expectedSize = [self GetTextHightForLable:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",incentives]];
    NSError *error;

    incentives = [NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                  error:&error];

    NSLog(@"DICT: %@", incentives);

    if( error )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        //MARK: COMMISION
        if (incentives[@"commission"][@"1"])
        {
            //enable flag
            _incentivesAndBenefits = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentJustified;

            [_incentivesAndBenefits setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, expectedSize.height+10)];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", incentives[@"commission"][@"1"]];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.numberOfLines=0;
            [cell addSubview:_incentivesAndBenefits];
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"commission"][@"1"]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"commission"][@"0"]);
            //return nil;
        }
        //MARK: EXTRAS
        if (incentives[@"extras"][@"1"])
        {
            //enable flag
            _incentivesAndBenefits = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentJustified;

            [_incentivesAndBenefits setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, expectedSize.height+10)];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", incentives[@"extras"][@"1"]];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.numberOfLines=0;
            [cell addSubview:_incentivesAndBenefits];
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"extras"][@"1"]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"extras"][@"0"]);
            //return nil;
        }
        //MARK: FOOD
        if (incentives[@"food"][@"1"])
        {
            //enable flag
            _incentivesAndBenefits = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentJustified;

            [_incentivesAndBenefits setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, expectedSize.height+10)];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", incentives[@"food"][@"1"]];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.numberOfLines=0;
            [cell addSubview:_incentivesAndBenefits];
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"food"][@"1"]);
        }
        else
        {
            //return nil;
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"food"][@"0"]);
        }
        //MARK: TRANSPORT
        if (incentives[@"transport"][@"1"])
        {
            //enable flag
            _incentivesAndBenefits = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentJustified;

            [_incentivesAndBenefits setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, expectedSize.height+10)];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", incentives[@"transport"][@"1"]];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.numberOfLines=0;
            [cell addSubview:_incentivesAndBenefits];
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"transport"][@"1"]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"transport"][@"0"]);
            //return nil;
        }
        //MARK: UNIFORM
        if (incentives[@"uniform"][@"1"])
        {
            //enable flag
            _incentivesAndBenefits = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentJustified;

            [_incentivesAndBenefits setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, expectedSize.height+10)];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", incentives[@"uniform"][@"1"]];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
            _incentivesAndBenefits.numberOfLines=0;
            [cell addSubview:_incentivesAndBenefits];
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"uniform"][@"1"]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",incentives[@"uniform"][@"0"]);
            //return nil;
        }
    }
}
//MARK: Mandatory Requirements
else if (indexPath.section==4) {
    _mandatoryRequirementLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    NSString *strDicription=[[[self.jobDetailDict objectForKey:@"sub_slots"]objectForKey:@"mandatory_requirements"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize expectedSize =[self GetTextHightForLable:strDicription];
    [_mandatoryRequirementLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, expectedSize.height+10)];
    _mandatoryRequirementLabel.text=strDicription;
    _mandatoryRequirementLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Light" size:14.0f];
    [cell addSubview:_mandatoryRequirementLabel];
    _mandatoryRequirementLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    _mandatoryRequirementLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The code for Mandatory Requirements works fine, returns the same number of cells as the one given by the API.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

PS: the data inside incentives is from the parsed son form the api.

Comment: Have you added the code to return the number of rows in section numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Put a break point to check those NSString have values

Comment: @BC_Dilum i am able to check and display which has value...my problem is, instead of displaying the data in section 3 it displays the data in section 4..

Comment: Can you please add full code on cellForRowAtIndexPath inside